# Cut and Paste into a sheet with Case-Select

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, case

I am new to writing macros and trying to write one for work. Below is a piece of code I have been fighting with. I want it to look at sheet "NG304" and find key words listed in column B. If the key words are there, move them to the second spreadsheet "Payroll Detail". Issues i'm having - the code is not going through the whole list and it doesn't seem to be pasting in the next available row on the payroll detail spreadsheet (it will simply paste on top of my header).

Code:

```
Dim Findme As String, Findwhat As String, c As Range

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NG304")

        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            Findwhat = vbNullString
            Findme = StrConv(c.Value2, vbProperCase)
            Select Case True
                Case Findme Like "VCIP"
                    Findwhat = "VCIP"
                Case Findme Like "Company Labor"
                    Findwhat = UCase(Findme)
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select

       If CBool(Len(Findwhat)) Then
                With .Parent.Worksheets("NG304")
                    c.EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Payroll Detail").Range("A" & lastrow + 1)
            lastrow = lastrow + 1
                End With
            End If
        Next c


    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will filter each value defined in K_WORDS (at the top), and move the rows to the other sheet:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub moveKeywordRows()
    Const K_WORDS  As String = "VCIP,Company Labor"      '<------- Defined keywords

    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, kw As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long

    Set wsFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NG304")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Payroll Detail")
    kw = Split(K_WORDS, ",")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(kw)
        lr = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With wsFrom.UsedRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & kw(i)
            .Copy
            wsDest.Cells(lr, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wsDest.Activate:    wsDest.Cells(1, "A").Select
    Next

    wsDest.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    With wsFrom
        .Activate   'wsFrom.UsedRange.AutoFilter '.ShowAllData
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

This is your posted code, with some adjustments - it seems to be working:

---

```
Public Sub moveKeywordRows1()
    Dim FindMe As String, FindWhat As String, c As Range, lr As Long, wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Payroll Detail")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NG304")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            FindMe = StrConv(c.Value2, vbProperCase)
            FindWhat = vbNullString
            Select Case UCase(FindMe)
                Case "VCIP":                    FindWhat = "VCIP"
                Case UCase("Company Labor"):    FindWhat = "Company Labor"
            End Select
            If Len(FindWhat) > 0 Then
                c.EntireRow.Cut Destination:=wsDest.Range("A" & lr + 1)
                lr = lr + 1
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I'm going to use the K_Words function since I have a handful of keywords to look for.

Thank you so much for your help!